# Why does this form not automatically populate my user's info ? Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A lot of this form has specific attributes for my payment provider, but I am trying to populate it with info from my `@user` object. But not working:

Specifically the `:placeholder` attributes on the form field under the `fields_for` outputs name of the attribute - in the First Name case, I see the words `first_name` instead of my user's first name, which would be `@user.first_name`.

```
<%= form_for :transaction,
         :params => @result && @result.params[:transaction],
         :errors => @result && @result.errors.for(:transaction),
         :builder => ApplicationHelper::BraintreeFormBuilder,
         :url => Braintree::TransparentRedirect.url,
         :html => {:autocomplete => "off"} do |f| -%>
      <%= field_set_tag "Customer" do -%>
        <%= f.fields_for :customer, @user do |c| -%>
          <div><%= c.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => :first_name %></div>
          <div><%= c.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => :last_name %></div>
          <div><%= c.text_field :email, :placeholder => :email %></div>
        <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Thoughts ?

P.S. I have truncated the form for brevity, but there is a `submit` button, etc. and the form works fine. It's just not populating my info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever plugin/gem you are using to add `:placeholder` to your `text_field`s is obviously not trying to grab the value of the `:first_name` attribute from the object of the form builder. It probably expects an actual value only: `:placeholder => @user.first_name`.